# Adding two running time from a function

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I have a method `Func()` that has two inner methods `Func1()` and `Func2()`.

`Func1()` has a running time of $O(k\lvert M^2 \rvert (\lvert L \rvert +\lvert M \rvert \log \lvert M \rvert))$ and `Func2()` has a running time of $O(k \lvert K \rvert \lvert V\rvert)$.

What is the running time of `Func()`?

Is it $\max \{ O(k\lvert M^2 \rvert (\lvert L \rvert +\lvert M \rvert \log \lvert M \rvert)),O(k \lvert K \rvert \lvert V\rvert)\} $? or $O(k\lvert M^2 \rvert (\lvert L \rvert +\lvert M \rvert \log \lvert M \rvert))+O(k \lvert K \rvert \lvert V\rvert)$?

If it is the latter one, how can it be simplified?

Comment: you have given two complexities for the same Func2(). The question is confusing at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The summation rule of the big-O notation;

Given $T_1(n) \in \mathcal{O}(f(n))$ and $T_2(n) \in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$, than $$T_1(n)+T_2(n) \in \mathcal{O}(\max(f(n),g(n)).$$

So, if you call $Func1()$ and $Func1()$ inside of your function $Func()$ only once and there is no other significant computation, $Func()$'s running time is;

$$Func() \in \mathcal{O}(\max(k |M^2|(|L|+|M|\log |M|), k | K | | V | )) $$